# QGIS v.net.salesman generates error when restricted to selected features

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin, travelling-salesman

I'm using the GRASS `v.net.salesman` in QGIS to find the shortest route between some American colleges on the road network. The network layer comes from Natural Earth Data, specifically ne_10m_roads_north_america. The source of the point data hardly matters. Any point layer has the same problem. The network is "repaired" first using `v.net operation=connect` to create a network such that all points of interest are connected to the network.

When attempting to use the "Selected features only" option on the nodes, the tool fails with:

```
ERROR: v.net.salesman: Sorry, <points> is not a valid parameter
```

It appears that QGIS is creating a temporary layer named "", but then is improperly feeding it to the GRASS tool. An obvious workaround is to export the selection to a separate layer. This is of course burdensome if one is interested in performing TSP for several different combinations of points.

What is the source of this error and how can it be avoided (other than the workaround I suggest)?

Image of processing tool options and log output follows.

[image: v.net.salesman dialog]

```
QGIS version: 3.24.1-Tisler
QGIS code revision: 5709b82461
Qt version: 5.12.8
Python version: 3.8.10
GDAL version: 3.4.0
GEOS version: 3.10.1-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 8.2.0, November 1st, 2021
PDAL version: 2.2.0 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2022-06-01T13:47:32
Algorithm 'v.net.salesman' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-g' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'arc_backward_column' : '', 'arc_column' : '', 'arc_type' : [0,1], 'center_cats' : '1-100000', 'input' : 'roads_north_america_connected.gpkg|layername=roads_north_america_connected', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'points' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('colleges_interested.gpkg|layername=colleges_interested', selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid), 'threshold' : 50 }

g.proj -c wkt="/tmp/processing_lGxYov/2aa35a1190fa4abaa08d19c0d27ed2d0/crs.prj"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/home/lee/Documents/Kallista/College/roads_north_america_connected.gpkg" layer="roads_north_america_connected" output="vector_6297a634ab1bd24" --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/tmp/processing_lGxYov/917be305db0d4b958b37213cd279b98d/points.shp" output="vector_6297a634b761725" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4041989.53966607 s=-2729545.13105786 e=3185262.74775124 w=-5996052.08793629
v.net.salesman input=vector_6297a634ab1bd24 points=vector_6297a634b761725 arc_type="line,boundary" center_cats="1-100000" output=outputf8c0446036e44f83ac034bb07988bdee --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="line" input="outputf8c0446036e44f83ac034bb07988bdee" output="/tmp/processing_lGxYov/2d6997f771794d91bd0e2cd3d344154b/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" layer=1 -c --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing </tmp/processing_lGxYov/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <roads_north_america_connected> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <roads_north_america_connected>...
Importing 49610 features (OGR layer <roads_north_america_connected>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_6297a634ab1bd24@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..20000..30000..40000..
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <points> contains polygons...
0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100
Creating attribute table for layer <points>...
Importing 10 features (OGR layer <points>)...
0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_6297a634b761725@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Creates a cycle connecting given nodes (Traveling salesman problem).
Usage:
v.net.salesman [-tg] input=name output=name center_cats=range
arc_layer=string arc_type=string[,string,...] node_layer=string
[arc_column=string] [arc_backward_column=string] [turn_layer=string]
[turn_cat_layer=string] [sequence=name] [--overwrite] [--help]
[--verbose] [--quiet] [--ui]
Flags:
-t Use turntable
-g Use geodesic calculation for longitude-latitude locations
Parameters:
input Name of input vector map
output Name for output vector map
center_cats Category values
arc_layer Arc layer
default: 1
arc_type Arc type
options: line,boundary
default: line,boundary
node_layer Node layer (used for cities)
default: 2
arc_column Arc forward/both direction(s) cost column (number)
arc_backward_column EXPERIMENTAL: Arc backward direction cost column (number)
turn_layer Layer with turntable
default: 3
turn_cat_layer Layer with unique categories used in turntable
default: 4
sequence Name for output file holding node sequence ("-" for stdout)
ERROR: v.net.salesman: Sorry, <points> is not a valid parameter
ERROR: Vector map <outputf8c0446036e44f83ac034bb07988bdee> not found
Execution of </tmp/processing_lGxYov/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing </tmp/processing_lGxYov/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
ERROR: Vector map <outputf8c0446036e44f83ac034bb07988bdee> not found
Execution of </tmp/processing_lGxYov/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 17.63 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /tmp/processing_lGxYov/2d6997f771794d91bd0e2cd3d344154b/output.gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```